# Chrome extension: access address bar programmatically?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to develop a Chrome extension that would allow me to directly type into the address bar after I open a new tab.  However, I couldn't find a way to access the address bar programmatically.  Could anyone help me on this issue?

Thank you!!

Comment: There's no API to fill the address bar with arbitrary text. What's your use case?

Comment: I have a use case for this.
1. I have my keyboard switched to a greek layout. 
2. I type "ςςς.γοογλε.ψομ" in the address bar.
3. While I still type, the plugin continuously replaces my characters to "www.google.com".

This is a very irritating problem for anyone who uses keyboard layouts that are not based on the latin alphabet. By doing that, one looses the ability to type non-latin URLs, but this is a sacrifice that I'd gladly make.